# Tailwind different themes

Tags: tailwind-css

I would like to ask if there is any way to use different themes with tailindcss.

Imagine your site has 2 themes - dark and light.

I have a button:

```
<button class="px-4 bg-blue over:bg-grey-100">Register</button>
```

This is for the ligth theme.

Is it possible to change the design of the button depending on the theme.

For example in the body i have class: "theme-light" or "theme-dark".

Is it possible to change the classes of the button to apply only for one of the themes.

Something like that **theme-dark:bg-orange**:

```
<button class="px-4 bg-blue over:bg-grey-100 theme-dark:bg-orange">Register</button>
```

If not is there any way to have different themes without writing custom css, or completely rewriting my html pages for the given theme.

If not what's the best way to have 2 or more themes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It is achievable to have `theme-dark` and `theme-light` variants by creating `pseudo-class` variants. It is detaily described here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/pseudo-class-variants/#creating-custom-variants

For example, to create `theme-dark` `pseudo-class` variant you can do something like this in your `tailwind.config.js` file:

```js
// tailwind.config.js
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    plugin(function({ addVariant, e }) {
      addVariant('theme-dark', ({ modifySelectors, separator }) => {
        modifySelectors(({ className }) => {
          return `.${e(`theme-dark${separator}${className}`)}:theme-dark`
        })
      })
    })
  ]
}
```

You can learn more about this here as well: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins/#adding-variants

However, to achieve what you want, you will need to have some `javascript` behavior that will have a state from which will be able to tell when it is `theme-light` and when it is `theme-dark`, which means this is not achievable with 100% only tailwind.

Also Adam Wathan created quick them of this here: https://github.com/adamwathan/theming-tailwind-demo

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you. I hoped it will be possible without javascript but maybe it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The [tw-colors](https://github.com/L-Blondy/tw-colors) plugin does what you want, the big advantage is that you don't need to use variants.

*tailwind.config.js*

```js
const { createThemes } = require('tw-colors');

   module.exports = {
      content: ['./src/**/*.{astro,html,js,jsx,md,mdx,svelte,ts,tsx,vue}'],
      plugins: [
         createThemes({
            halloween: { 
               'primary': 'orange',
               'secondary': 'yellow',
            },
            summer: { 
               'primary': 'pink',
               'secondary': 'red',
            },
            winter: { 
               'primary': 'blue',
               'secondary': 'green',
            },
            party: { 
               'primary': 'steelblue',
               'secondary': 'darkblue',
            },
         })
      ],
   };
```

use themes like this with class:

```html
<html class='theme-halloween'>
      ...
</html>
```

Or with data attributes:

```html
<html data-theme='halloween'>
      ...
</html>
```

Themes can be switched dynamically with some toggle button or whatever you prefer