# How to create multiple themes using Tailwind CSS?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Looking at Tailwind CSS, it seems that you need to specify specific colors in your classes like this:

```
<div class="bg-yellow-200 dark:bg-gray-800"></div>
```

But what if I want to offer 10 different themes that users can choose from in my web app? Like I might have themes like `halloween` and `summer` and `winter` and `party` etc.

I know that with regular CSS this is very easy done like this:

```
[data-theme="halloween"] {
    --color-bg: #000;
    --color-body: #757981;
}

<body data-theme="halloween"></div>
```

And then using Javascript I can change the data-theme property and the theme will change.

But how could I do this with Tailwind CSS? I couldn't find anything in the documentation about this.

Comment: Have you tried the docs? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme

Comment: @Quentin I see it only talks about how to configure the default theme not how to add more themes.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be as simple as adding themes to the configuration. It seems like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61050423/5963874) might point you in the right direction. It suggests using a plugin to add prefixes to class names which use CSS variables that define the theme.

Answer (score 32):

I did actually find a solution using CSS variables.

In your CSS file, you can define your styles for each theme like this

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  html[data-theme='default'] {
    --color-esther: 34, 39, 46;
    --color-maximus: 45, 51, 59;
    --color-linx: 55, 62, 71;
  }

  html[data-theme='neon'] {
    --color-esther: 20, 61, 42;
    --color-maximus: 13, 82, 66;
    --color-linx: 20, 82, 11;
  }
}
```

Then in your `tailwind.config.js` file you can define them like this

**Tailwind version ^3.1**

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      esther: 'rgb(var(--color-esther) / <alpha-value>)',
      maximus: 'rgb(var(--color-maximus) / <alpha-value>)',
      linx: 'rgb(var(--color-linx) / <alpha-value>)',
    },
  },
}
```

**Tailwind less than version 3.1**

```js
function withOpacity(cssVariable) {
  return ({ opacityValue }) => {
    return opacityValue ? `rgba(var(${cssVariable}), ${opacityValue})` : `rgb(var(${cssVariable}))`
  }
}

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      esther: withOpacity('--color-esther'),
      maximus: withOpacity('--color-maximus'),
      linx: withOpacity('--color-linx'),
    },
  },
}
```

And in your HTML, you can use these classes like this:

```html
<html lang="en" data-theme="default">
  <body class="bg-esther text-optimus cursor-default"></body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems like an awesome solution, but after following your steps I get `--color-esther` is not defined https://imgur.com/a/FnkeB3p

Comment: @Justin please provide a full code example so I can take a look at it and see what's wrong

Comment: @MartinZeltin what sense does it make to add attribute selector in base layer? usually its used for tag selectors only

Comment: @Justin I'm guessing you forgot to apply the `data-theme="default"` HTML attribute

Comment: From Tailwind 3.1 you can now entirely remove the `withOpacity` function and instead use a format string like this `primary: 'rgb(var(--color-primary) / <alpha-value>)'` https://tailwindcss.com/blog/tailwindcss-v3-1#easier-css-variable-color-configuration

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple of plugins that support defining multiple Tailwind themes, and switching between them. I particularly like the [thailwindcss-themer plugin](https://github.com/RyanClementsHax/tailwindcss-themer) because it allows you to:

- switch themes by simply adding a css class with the name of the theme on any component (usually the top-level component)
- use CSS classes like you would normally do (e.g. `text-primary`). This keeps code clean and independent of the plugin (contrary to other plugins, which sometimes require a specific prefix on every CSS class)
- use variants to further finetune styling, e.g. `my-theme:font-bold`

Answer (score 7):

[tw-colors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tw-colors) does exactly that.

*tailwind.config.js*

```js
const { createThemes } = require('tw-colors');

   module.exports = {
      content: ['./src/**/*.{astro,html,js,jsx,md,mdx,svelte,ts,tsx,vue}'],
      plugins: [
         createThemes({
            halloween: { 
               'primary': 'orange',
               'secondary': 'yellow',
            },
            summer: { 
               'primary': 'pink',
               'secondary': 'red',
            },
            winter: { 
               'primary': 'blue',
               'secondary': 'green',
            },
            party: { 
               'primary': 'steelblue',
               'secondary': 'darkblue',
            },
         })
      ],
   };
```

use themes like this with class:

```html
<html class='theme-halloween'>
      ...
</html>
```

Or with data attributes:

```html
<html data-theme='halloween'>
      ...
</html>
```

Then use tailwind classes as you normally would. A button with the class `bg-primary` will change color according to the closest theme.

Themes can be switched dynamically with some toggle button or whatever you prefer

Comment: Thank for you for this, very helpful! Would you mind adding a [note](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) that you are the author of this package?

Comment: This plugin did fit like a glove. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just stumpled upon this question as I am doing the same what I already did a few years ago but couldn't remember anymore. In case anybody comes here again, maybe this answer might be helpful.

In our case, we are building a theme that is applied to 3 different websites but obviously changes colors and fonts, which seems to be the same case the question author has.

For this, [tailwind presets](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/presets) can be used. I have one `tailwind.preset.js` which is basically the default tailwind configuration with all the base colors, spacings etc. For each theme, a separate `tailwind.<theme-name>.js` is set up that contains the changes and bases itself on the preset.

Example `tailwind.theme-one.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    require('./tailwind.preset.js')
  ],
  theme: {
    colors: {
      # color changes go here
    }
  }
}
```

We have a gulp workflow set up that basically just renders the main scss file once for each theme configuration. On the integrations, the required theme file is being loaded then.

Answer (score 0):

If top answer is not working, you may need to remove commas like this:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  html[data-theme='default'] {
    --color-esther: 34 39 46;
    --color-maximus: 45 51 59;
    --color-linx: 55 62 71;
  }

  html[data-theme='neon'] {
    --color-esther: 20 61 42;
    --color-maximus: 13 82 66;
    --color-linx: 20 82 11;
  }
}
```

I'm currently using Tailwindcss v3.3.5